# An error occurred (AuthorizationHeaderMalformed) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The authorization header is malformed;

Tags: gitlab

this is my gitlab ci
stages:

- pipeline

package:
stage: pipeline
script:
- apt-get update -qy
- apt-get install -y awscli jq zip
- zip -r 55seconds.zip .
- aws configure set aws_access_key_id "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"
- aws configure set aws_secret_access_key "$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
- aws configure set default.region "me-central-1"
- aws s3 ls
only:
- master

im getting this error
An error occurred (AuthorizationHeaderMalformed) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The authorization header is malformed; a non-empty Access Key (AKID) must be provided in the credential.

i declared the variables correctly as shown in the picture and i'm very sure of the values